# VueJS <input> value change not calling @change

Tags: javascript, vue.js

With VueJS, I have two seperate components.

A modal and a form.

In the modal form, the user inputs a PIN that gets confirmed then this value is set to an input tag in the form to basically save this value.

In the modal component, I set the value simply like this:

`document.getElementById('pin').value = this.pin_input;`

Within the form component, the input tag is like this:

`<input type="hidden" @change="submit()" id="pin">`

In the console, the value of this input tag get's set correctly, though the `@change="submit()"` is not getting called when the values changes.

submit method code within form component that is not getting called:

```
methods : {
   submit : function(){
       console.log("SUBMIT HERE");
   }    
}
```

Why is my input tag's `@change` not getting called?

Comment: this is not a correct implementation. You should adhere to the vue js models and data properties.

Comment: You shouldn't set values by using DOM manipulations because Vue doesn't watch for DOM changes (only it's own virtual DOM) thus they are completely disregarded and are overwritten on next update tick. Your problem can probably be solved but you need to share your component's code.

Comment: @dziraf ok thanks, I did not know that. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Setting the value on a DOM element does not fire the input / change events. This is why the event listener you set in vue is not called.

You can fire those events manually, they will then be picked up by vue.

```
var element = document.getElementById('pin');
element.value = this.pin_input;
// Works in most modern browsers.
var event = new Event('change');
element.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, For communication between components it's better to use:

1. some state management like Vues https://vuex.vuejs.org/, and save input value  in separate store
   or
2. try with custom methods https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html
3. use parent component and pass callback into child components.

@change will not work in your case